# options for enhanced lookup column in "new experience" SharePoint Online

Tags: lookup-column, list-view-threshold, new-experience

I have a site in SharePoint online which is using a lookup column to a large list (like 25k) of items.  I'm getting the list view threshold error when trying to add metadata with that lookup column.  I've done research and found some options to solve this, mostly using jquery, but they all apply to the new and edit forms (this includes everything I found in the app store, github and 3rd party).  I have been unable to find any solution that works with the current state of SharePoint Online, which is the new experience or "modern" view.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution to deal with the lookup limit of 5000 in the new experience?

I've considered switching back to classic experience but that isn't a long term solution I'm sure so I need to weigh all options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the threshold is not something you can change the limit, for both Classic and modern experience the limit of the items you can request is 5000.

you'll have to find a workaround where you don't request more than 5000 items from the server or create filtered views to ask less then 5000

Comment: I know it can't be changed, that's why I'm looking for a solution.  There are ways to deal with it out there but all apply to the new/edit form pages and not the "new experience" so I don't know how to apply them